# String interpolation and code injection

Tags: python-3.x

Is the method

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
# ...
temp = input("Enter your template, use {name} in order to insert the name of the user")
print(temp.format(name=name))
```

sensible to code injection ? Here is my use case: on a website, I want to provide my users a mean to write content with some dynamic values. In other words, I want to provide my users a minimalistic template language, just replace a name by a value.

Is possible to do something else than the replacement I want with the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not relevant for the statement you posted.  More realistic is

```
s = input('enter something> ')
print('tem {} plate'.format(s))
```

The answer **for 3.x**[1] is that `s` is never evaluated and the string is copied as it into the template, so this should be safe

[1] For 2.x, use `raw_input` as `input` **does** evaluate the string, which is dangerous.

Comment: Why is my question not relevant for the statement I posted ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that the example statement is not relevant to the question because with `foo` being bound to a simple literal, there is no question of code injection (from outside the program).

Comment: I've edited my question, it is more realistic for my use case.